# How do I specify font size for headings in my Latex file? Also Contents page is not showing 'abstract' 'acknolwdgement''

Tags: formatting, pdftex, titlesec

**% I want chapter heading {INTRO} to be of font 16, section heading of 14, and %subsection of 12.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
     \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
     {\filcenter\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
     {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
     {1pt}{\LARGE}
     {}
     \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-0.6in}{0pt}

     \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{8pt}{16pt}

   \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{12pt}

   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  

    \begin{document}
% Content starts
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \input{Declaration}
    \input{Acknowledgements}
    \input{abstract}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \input{Abbreviations}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \input{Intro}
    \input{Review}


    \bibliography{References}
    %\bibliographystyle{spbasic} 
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Try replacing, in `\titleformat{\chapter}...`\Large` with `\fontsize{16}{20}\selectfont`, and similarly for the other section levels.

Comment: Thankyou but it showed an error. So i wrote the command \fontsize{} in \chapter{\fontsize{16} Intro}. can you help with table of contents also? It shows 1. Intro, 1.1 section , 2 . Review .......... but I also want declaration, abstract and acknoledgement to show in table of contents.

Comment: For the last point, use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}` (just after `\input{Declaration}`, or maybe inside the input file, just after `\chapter*{Declaration}`, and similarly for the other input files. For the first point, I do not understand what you did exactly. The font size commands should be written in the 3rd argument of `\titleformat`, in the place of `\Large`. If it doesn't work, please post a minimal, but compilable, example code.

Comment: thank a lot for [\addcontentline]. It worked! For the first part I used [ [\usepackage{titlesec}
     \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
     {\filcenter\normalfont\fontsize{16}\bfseries}
     {{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
     {1pt}{\LARGE}
     {} ]

Comment: \fontsize requires two arguments (the first arument is the font size itself, and the second  is the interline skip for this fontsize) and must add `\selectfont` to make it work.